# wired junit test assert

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, assert

Hi i have the following junit test

```
@Test
public void testTest() {
    AddressEntity entity = null;
    assert (entity.getStatus() == StatusType.REMOVED);
}
```

in eclipse it goes green, maven finds the error.

Why does it in eclipse not throw an error?

Comment: How are you running in eclipse?

Comment: rightclick -> run as -> junit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven enables assertions by default. [See surefire official doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions)

Eclipse does not enables assetions by default. You can enable them by adding -ea in your JVM options. [See Oracle official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

In you consider a UnitTest, you should use Assert.assertSame(). [See JUnit official doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

Cant find the actual reason why eclipse is ignoring java's assert keyword .

But I suggest you don't use java's assert in your JUnit. It's not an informative assertion and a bad practice.
Use one of org.junit.Assert asserts. it will work both in eclipse / maven.

good luck.